Power Amplifier Envelope tracking Technique
Envelope tracking is a widely used technique used to improve the efficiency of a power amplifier.
the power supply voltage applied to the RF power amplifier is basically modulated by the signal envelope in order to ensure that the amplifier is operating at peak efficiency for the power required at each instant of transmission
The power supply needs to be able to accomodate the BW of the envelope which is 2-3 times higher than the BW of the RF signal.
I fail to understand why does the envelope have a higher BW than the RF signal since this envelope is nothing but the envelope of the RF signal itself?
